# Output variables becomes 0. Possible logic error

Tags: c, while-loop, logic, output

I declare and then assign 'n' to the variables 'm' and 'num'. By the time they reach the end of the program they end up zero.

This program is works to find the Phi Totient function of n. It all works flawlessly until the very last while loop.

```
int factorization(int n)
{
 int i, j=0, a[14], index=0, m, num;

    m=n;
    num=n;

    for(i=2; i<sqrt(n)+1; i++)
    {
        if(n%i == 0)
        {
           n=n/i;
            if(a[0]!=i && a[1]!=i && a[2]!=i && a[3]!=i && a[4]!=i && a[5]!=i && a[6]!=i && a[! =i && a[8]!=i && a[9]!=i && a[10]!=i && a[11]!=i && a[12]!=i && a[13]!=i && a[14]!=i)
            {
            a[index]=i;
            index++;
            }
           i=1;
        }
    }
    a[index]=n;

    for (i=index+1; i<=14; i++)
    {
        a[i]=0;
    }
    for (i=0; i<=10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }

    while(a[j] != 0 && a[j] != 1)
    {
    m=m*((a[j]-1)/a[j]);
    j++;
    }
    printf("Phi of %d = %d", num, m);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change *m* to *double* and loop to

```
while (a[j] != 0 && a[j] != 1)
{
    m = m * ( ((double)a[j] - 1.0) / (double)a[j] );
    j++;
}
```

If m is integer when ever the division

```
((a[j]-1)/a[j])
```

is less than 1 it is rounded down to zero and the multiplication becomes

```
m = m * 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i, j=0, a[14], index=0, m, num;
```

`a` array is not initialized but the array elements are read in:

```
if(a[0]!=i && a[1]!=i && a[2]!=i && a[3]!=i && a[4]!=i && a[5]!=i && a[6]!=i && a[! =i && a[8]!=i && a[9]!=i && a[10]!=i && a[11]!=i && a[12]!=i && a[13]!=i && a[14]!=i)
```

Morever in the above line you are testing `a[14]!=i`  but the last element of `a` is `a[13]`. `a[14]` is out of the array.

Same in:

```
for (i=index+1; i<=14; i++)
{
    a[i]=0;
}
```

You are accessing an element (`a[14]`) outside the array.

Comment: That fixed the variable 'num' for me, but not the variable 'm'. I also initialized all the elements of array 'a'.

Comment: it seems that my 'm' variable becomes 0 some how and just computes and become 0...